# Trying to load UIViewController after click of item in TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I feel like this is a fairly easy question, but I've tried for hours and can't seem to get it.  I'm trying to create an app that calculates different equations that are critical to my job.  Essentially, I've grouped the calculations into categories using nested TableViewControllers.  This part works.

The part I am trying to figure out is how to push to a UIViewController so I can actually have the user enter data to do the calculations.  For some reason I can't seem to get it to work.  I am using Xcode 5 and am using Storyboards.

Really sorry for the long post.  I've also included a screenshot of the storyboard at the following link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF5YK.jpg

code below:

**Root TableViewController Code (RootTableViewController.m)**

```
#import "RootTableViewController.h"
#import "calculatorTableViewController.h"

@interface RootTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation RootTableViewController{
    NSArray *calculatorOptions;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    calculatorOptions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"General", @"Digital", @"Print", @"Television", nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [calculatorOptions count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CalculatorCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [calculatorOptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"calculatorDetails"]){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        calculatorTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.calculationType = [calculatorOptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.title = destViewController.calculationType;
    }

}


@end
```

**Secondary TableViewController.h file (calculatorTableViewController.h)**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface calculatorTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *calculationType;


@end
```

**Secondary TableViewController.m file (calculatorTableViewController.m)**

```
#import "calculatorTableViewController.h"
#import "CalculateGrpsHaveRF.h"


@interface calculatorTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation calculatorTableViewController{
    NSArray *general;
    NSArray *digital;
    NSArray *print;
    NSArray *television;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    general = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Calculate GRPs (Have R & F)", @"Calculate Reach (Have GRPs & F)", @"Calculate Frequency (Have GRPs & R)", @"CPM to CPP", @"CPP to CPM", nil];

    digital = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Calculate Impressions (Have cost & CPM)", @"Calculate CPM (Have cost & impressions)", @"Calculate Cost (Have CPM and Impressions)", @"Calculate ASF", @"Calculate CPC/CPA/CPV", nil];

    print = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Calculate CPM", @"Calculate GRPs", @"Calculate CPP", nil];

    television = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Universe Estimates", @"Calculate GRPs", @"Calculate Spots", @"Calculate Average Rating", @"Calculate Total Impressions", @"Calculate CPP", nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([_calculationType isEqualToString:@"General"]){
        return [general count];
    }
    else if ([_calculationType isEqualToString:@"Digital"]){
        return [digital count];
    }
    else if ([_calculationType isEqualToString:@"Print"]){
        return [print count];
    }
    else if ([_calculationType isEqualToString:@"Television"]){
        return [television count];
    }
    return 0;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Calculator2Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    if ([_calculationType isEqualToString:@"General"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [general objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    }

    else if ([_calculationType isEqualToString:@"Digital"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [digital objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    }

    else if ([_calculationType isEqualToString:@"Print"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [print objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    }

    else if ([_calculationType isEqualToString:@"Television"]) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [television objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    }

    return cell;
}


-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Calculate GRPs (Have R & F)"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    CalculateGrpsHaveRF *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.Title = [general objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want calculatorTableViewController to perform segue to next view.

```
//when you select a row
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    //perform a segue
    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"your_segue_identifier" sender:your_sender];
    } 
    else if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"another_segue_identifier" sender:your_sender];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     //prepare your segue here
}
```

Comment: Pretty much, yes.  I've edited the original post to show the seague.  Does this make sense

Comment: If you have set segue identifier in storyboard to "Calculate GRPs (Have R & F)", then it should be working. But, I suggest you rename identifier to something like show_calculate_grps to make it simplier.

Comment: Thanks so much.  That seemed to do it.  However I'm now trying to connect multiple UIViewControllers to the TableViewController - if you click one cell in the table view controller, it takes you to one UIViewController, but if you click another cell, it takes you to another UIViewController.  Does that make sense?

Comment: There are many different ways to do this. The simplest way would be to have multiple segues in the storyboard and call performSegueWithIdentifier with different identifier.

Comment: I set up another segue with another view controller, but for some reason, all of the cells in the tableviewcontroller are pushing to the same new view controller.

Comment: Make sure you set different identifier for each segue in the storyboard and use different identifier in performSegueWithIdentifier. I have edited my answer, please check.